# How to pass a Multidimensional array through a prototype?

Tags: javascript

## Problem

Whenever I call the `arrayGuide` I get an `error`

```js
Array.prototype.arrayGuide = function() {
  console.log(this) // When called… this should be getting logged.
}
//How to get this prototype to work


replace = {
  basic: {
    stage1: {
      one: ["hello", "world"],
      two: ["brother", "sister"],
      three: ["baby", "adult"]
    },
    stage2: {
      one: ["1"],
      two: ["2"],
      three: ["3"]
    }
  },
  advanced: {
    humans: [/^biology\s/gi, /science$/i]
  }
}

replace.arrayGuide() // This keeps throwing an error message
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Results I should be getting

I should be getting these results from the first demo. But for some reason, I'm not.

```js
function arrayRegExpCreator(place) {
  console.log(place) // I should be getting this…
}

replace = {
  basic: {
    stage1: {
      one: ["hello", "world"],
      two: ["brother", "sister"],
      three: ["baby", "adult"]
    },
    stage2: {
      one: ["1"],
      two: ["2"],
      three: ["3"]
    }
  },
  advanced: {
    humans: [/^biology\s/gi, /science$/i]
  }
}

arrayRegExpCreator(replace)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet is extending `Array` prototype not `Object`. Since `replace` is an instance of the `Object`, you should do this:

```
Object.prototype.arrayGuide = function() {
  console.log(this) // When called… this should be getting logged.
}
```

```js
Object.prototype.arrayGuide = function() {
  console.log(this) // When called… this should be getting logged.
}
//How to get this prototype to work


replace = {
  basic: {
    stage1: {
      one: ["hello", "world"],
      two: ["brother", "sister"],
      three: ["baby", "adult"]
    },
    stage2: {
      one: ["1"],
      two: ["2"],
      three: ["3"]
    }
  },
  advanced: {
    humans: [/^biology\s/gi, /science$/i]
  }
}

replace.arrayGuide() // This keeps throwing an error message
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that prototypes of native objects should not be modified if it's not a polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the array prototype, not the object prototype

change it to:

```
Object.prototype.arrayGuide = function () {
  console.log(this);
}
```

also...

never extend the prototypes of native objects unless it is a polyfill